# visual studio 2010 + sql server 2008 datagrid/database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview, vb.net-2010

please help
im newbie in programming
im using vb.net and sql server 2008

instead of deleting data from datagrid/database i want to use highlight
if i double click the selected data that i want to delete
how can i highlight it

this is my code :

```
Private Sub dgvDoctorsList_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvDoctorsList.CellDoubleClick

     If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to delete this data ?", "CONFIRMATION", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
      If e.RowIndex > -1 Then
       dgvDoctorsList.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Cyan
      End If
      End If

end sub
```

when everytime i close the program the highlighted data will become unhighlighted
how can i fix this
i want the highlighted data will still highlighted even if the program closed and run it again

sorry for my wrong grammar, please help thanks in advance

Comment: changing row's backcolor will not change real row's condition ..

Comment: sir please help . i don't want to delete data from database instead of deleting data i would like to use highlight . therefore highlight means deleted but the data should still in the database also in datagridview

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a column in your database table which indicates whether that row was deleted or not
Like 1 for deleted and 0 for not deleted
In form load, read the database and highlight rows which has that column value as 1

Comment: sir can you give me the code im newbie in here thanks in advance